# MAMP ext mongo.so not loading. How to fix it?

Tags: php, mongodb, config, mamp, ini

I know there's multiple post about this, but I tried almost everything i found out ..

My problem is that I'm trying to add `mongo.so` to my MAMP server. It compiles perfectly with the phpize of MAMP and php-config of MAMP. But when I'm trying to put it in the `php.ini`, it doesn't load it ..

```
php --version :
    PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Jul 25 2014 17:02:08) 
    Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

phpize -v :
    Configuring for:
    PHP Api Version:         20100412
    Zend Module Api No:      20100525
    Zend Extension Api No:   220100525

php --ini :
    Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf
    Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf/php.ini
    Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
    Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

I tried changing that `php.ini`, restart and nothing ..

I tried changing the `php.ini` in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.5.14/`, restart and nothing ..

What else is needed to adjust to fix it?

EDIT:

I just found out that the `PHP API` on my `phpinfo()` page is set to `20121113`. What I don't understand is why that doesn't take the same version on my `phpize` related to the php server ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed it myself. For everybody passing by, please note that this was my PHP sources that was not in the good version. So the extension was not configuring with the right version.